# Why I'm not getting any data even after successfully loading the HTML in $dom object?

Tags: php, foreach, domdocument

I'm having following function code to clean up the HTML data.

```
function clear_question_data($html) {  
        $dom = new DOMDocument();

        $dom->loadHTML($html);/*Here the HTML data is loading perfectly, it's returning TRUE here*/
        die(var_dump($dom));/*This statement gives output as object(DOMNodeList)#11 (0) { }*/

        /*$test = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img'); 
        die(var_dump($test));*/
        foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $image)
        {   echo "In a loop"; die;
            $image->removeAttribute('alt');
            $image->removeAttribute('xmlns');
            $image->removeAttribute('title');
        }
        echo "Out of the loop"; die;

            $txt=$dom->saveHTML();

            $dom->loadHTML($txt);

            foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $image)
            {
                $srcval=$image->getAttribute('src');

                $srcval = htmlspecialchars_decode($srcval);

                $srcval = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $srcval);  

                if(strpos($srcval,"%5C%22")==0)
                {           
                    $srcval = str_replace("%5C%22", "", $srcval);
                    $srcval = str_replace(".png%5C%22", ".png", $srcval);
                }
                if(strpos($srcval,"../../..")==0)
                {           
                    $srcval = str_replace("../../..", "", $srcval);
                }
                if(strpos($srcval,"../..")==0)
                {           
                    $srcval = str_replace("../..", "", $srcval);
                }
                if(strpos($srcval,"/ckeditor_3.6.1//plugins")==0) 
                {           
                    $srcval = str_replace("/ckeditor_3.6.1//", EPN_SITE_URL."ckeditor_3.6.1/", $srcval);
                }


                  $srcval = str_replace(".png/\"", ".png", $srcval);
                  $srcval = str_replace("�", "-", $srcval);

                $image->setAttribute('src',$srcval);
            }   
            $final_data=$dom->saveHTML();

            return $final_data;
    }
```

I'm not getting after successfully loading the HTML data why I'm getting this null result? Due to this nul result I'm not able to get inside the foreach loop and in turn nothing is working from my function. Can anyone help me in correcting the issue, please? The argument(HTML data) I'm passing is as follows:

```
$html=Glucose when hetaed with CH&lt;sub&gt;3&lt;/sub&gt;OH in presence of dry HCl gas gives&lt;img align=&quot;middle&quot; alt=&quot;�math xmlns=�http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML���mi��#945;�/mi��/math�&quot; class=&quot;Wirisformula&quot; src=&quot;/ckeditor_3.6.1//plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=dedbf6a559a928eeeaee82c4b1bf40d3.png&quot; title=&quot;Double click to edit&quot;&gt; and &lt;img align=&quot;middle&quot; alt=&quot;�math xmlns=�http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML���mi��#946;�/mi��/math�&quot; class=&quot;Wirisformula&quot; src=&quot;/ckeditor_3.6.1//plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=2c5cf4a4494a03be06d6c32308a225ba.png&quot; title=&quot;Double click to edit&quot;&gt;-methyl glycosides because it contains.&lt;br&gt;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The script exits when you call `die()`.

Comment: @Barmar: I put die just for the purpose of debugging. If you remove die and let the program execute it's way, it's not getting inside foreach loop as the $dom object contains nothing(i.e.null). To know the value of $dom I put die, that's it. My issue is why after loading the HTML successfully the object is showing me the null value and the control flow is not getting inside foreach loop? Can you help me in this regard, please?

Comment: Why don't you just put `var_dump()` instead of `die(var_dump())`?

Comment: @Barmar:Because I wanted to stop the execution of the program after checking the value in $dom object. My main issue is how to get inside the foreach loop? Do you have any solution for it?

Comment: As far as I can tell your code is working for me. The sample HTML you provided is a little garbled so it's hard to tell for sure.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider:If it's working for you then what could be the issue on my side? Why the $dom object is containing null and the control flow is not getting inside foreach loop? Do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

You should make html decode before load to Dom

P.s. I use define('EPN_SITE_URL', 'example.com');

```
echo clear_question_data(html_entity_decode($html));

$ php ~/test.php
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>Glucose when hetaed with CH<sub>3</sub>OH in presence of dry HCl gas gives<img align="middle" class="Wirisformula" src="example.comckeditor_3.6.1/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=dedbf6a559a928eeeaee82c4b1bf40d3.png"> and <img align="middle" class="Wirisformula" src="example.comckeditor_3.6.1/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=2c5cf4a4494a03be06d6c32308a225ba.png">-methyl glycosides because it contains.<br></p></body></html>
```